# How to toggle between three div's and two icons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When i click on one of the div the icon changes and it stays changed i want it when i click on it again to change back to how it was and to deselect itself is there any way i can change this without changing my code too much any suggestion?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
}

function myFunction1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo1");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
}

function myFunction2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo2");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
}

$('.column1').click(function() {
  var collapsed = $(this).find('i').hasClass('fas fa-check');
  $('.example-class').find('i').removeClass('fas fa-check-circle');
  $('.example-class').find('i').addClass('fas fa-check');
  if (collapsed)
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-check fas fa-check-circle')
});
```

```css
.change {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="row1">
  <div id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Learn</h2>
    <p>I'm here to</p>
    <p>look around</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo1" onclick="myFunction1()" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Start</h2>
    <p>I want to find my</p>
    <p>first help desk</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo2" onclick="myFunction2()" class="column1 clk">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Switch</h2>
    <p>I'm interested in</p>
    <p>swtiching help desks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Simplified jQuery solution

```
$('.column1').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

**You don't need function or separate id for that just need a common class**

```js
$('.column1').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* Usefull CSS */

.column1.active{
  color:blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
 
}
.fs5::before{
  content:'\f00c';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
  font-weight: 900; 
  
}
.active .fs5::before{
  content:'\f058';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
  font-weight: 900;   
}
/* Just Some random CSS */

.column1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px 
}
.column1 * {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="row1">
  <div class="column1">
    <span class="fs5"></span>
    <h2>Learn</h2>
    <p>I'm here to</p>
    <p>look around</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column1 active">
    <span class="fs5"></span>
    <h2>Start</h2>
    <p>I want to find my</p>
    <p>first help desk</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <span class="fs5"></span>
    <h2>Switch</h2>
    <p>I'm interested in</p>
    <p>swtiching help desks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution but, i wanted them to be able to toggle between when one is selected i click the other one and the one that was selected gets deselected

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  // Toggle the class on main element
  el.classList.toggle("change");
  // Toggle both check and circle check classes
  el.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-check')
  el.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-check-circle')
}
```

```css
.change {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="row1">
  <div id="demo" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Learn</h2>
    <p>I'm here to</p>
    <p>look around</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo1" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Start</h2>
    <p>I want to find my</p>
    <p>first help desk</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo2" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="column1 clk">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Switch</h2>
    <p>I'm interested in</p>
    <p>swtiching help desks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Modified your `click(function(){});`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
  
}

function myFunction1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo1");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
}

function myFunction2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("demo2");
  element.classList.toggle("change");
}

$('.column1').click(function() {
  var collapsed = $(this).find('i').hasClass('fas fa-check');
  if (collapsed)
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-check fas fa-check-circle')
    
    if(!collapsed)
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fas fa-check fas fa-check-circle')

});
```

```css
.change {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="row1">
  <div id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Learn</h2>
    <p>I'm here to</p>
    <p>look around</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo1" onclick="myFunction1()" class="column1">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Start</h2>
    <p>I want to find my</p>
    <p>first help desk</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo2" onclick="myFunction2()" class="column1 clk">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    <h2>Switch</h2>
    <p>I'm interested in</p>
    <p>swtiching help desks</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does but the only problem is that they all end up being selected, i wanted them to be able to toggle between when one is selected i click the other one and the one that was selected gets deselected

Answer (score 0):

Just recommendation.
Do you know alpin.js?
It will make it easy.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"
        defer></script>

<div class="row1" x-data="sampleData">
    <template x-for="item in items">
        <div id="demo" @click="check($event, item)" class="column1"
             :class="{change:item.checked}">
            <i class="fas"
               :class="item.checked?'fa-check-circle':'fa-check'"></i>
            <h2 x-text="item.title"></h2>
            <p x-text="item.line1"></p>
            <p x-text="item.line2"></p>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>

<style>
    .change {
        border-color: blue;
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

<script>
window.sampleData = {
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Lean',
            line1: 'I am here to',
            line2:'look arround',
            checked: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Start',
            line1: 'I want to find my',
            line2: 'first help desk',
            checked: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Switch',
            line1: 'I\'m interested in',
            line2: 'swtiching help desks',
            checked: false
        },
    ],
    check(e, item) {
        item.checked = !item.checked
    }
}
```

Comment: No i dont know alpin.js but thank you for the suggestion